# milliseconds in java.util.Date are not well interpreted

Tags: java, date, milliseconds

I have two dates in java with format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS. I need to do a simple arithmetic operation.  My code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"); 
String out = resu.getString(3);
Date dateOut = formatter.parse(out);
String in = resu.getString(4);
Date dateIn = formatter.parse(in);
long msDiff = dateOut.getTime() - dateIn.getTime();
```

this works fine if both dates have 3 milliseconds, for example:

```
dateIn = 2015-10-14 16:32:20.037
dateOut = 2015-10-14 16:32:20.093
```

But when a date has one or two digits instead of complete the value with zeros at right it do it at left, which of course changes the result of the operation.  Example.

```
dateIn = 2015-10-14 16:32:20.05
dateOut = 2015-10-14 16:32:20.067

dateOut - dateIn = 062 //this is wrong, it should be 067 - 050 = 17.
```

What I am doing wrong?

I didnt find a good solution, so I made a workaround that works fine.  It checks the number of milliseconds digits and returns always three.

```
public static String completeDate (String date) {
    String digits = date.substring(date.indexOf("."));
    int cantDigits = digits.length();
    while (cantDigits < 4){
        digits = digits + "0";
        cantDigits = digits.length();
    }
    String newDate = date.substring(0,date.indexOf(".")) + digits;
    return newDate;
}
```

Comment: How are you *reading* the dates?

Comment: Indeed - please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Note that if you have a value ending in ".05" then you *don't* have dates in a format ending with "ss.SSS".

Comment: values are in a database, I take the value from a resultset and then parse it with SimpleDateFormat

Comment: Please edit your code and add the extra information.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code.

Comment: Either make sure, the values in the database have always the same format, or (if you're not the one writing these values to the database) always pad your time string with the missing trailing zeros till it reaches the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`. I wouldn't prefer parsing with different formats.

Comment: A different program writes the values in the database, I can't change that. How can I pad mi time with the missing trailing zeros as you mention?

Answer (score 4):

The two dates have technically different patterns because of the different number of digits after the decimal point. From the [documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Pattern letters are usually repeated, as their number determines the exact presentation:
>
> ...
>
> For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

Given this, the date `2015-10-14 16:32:20.05` is interpreted as `2015-10-14 16:32:20.005` (the fraction is padded with a zero to have three digits), hence the difference of 62 millisec. You should use different formatters for the two dates or most probably should look up how these two values have been inserted and why they have different formatting.

Comment: Ok, I see, in the database the values are correct, 05 is the same than 050, so is not necessary to add the final zero.  I can use different patters because I dont know how many digits the value will have, it could be 1, 2 or 3.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: what you explain may be correct, but it doesnt explain why it converts .05 to 005

Comment: @user3285427 I mentioned why in the documentation _"For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount"_.

Answer (score 0):

If they are converted to `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date` through `SimpleDateFormat`, then the `timestamp1.getTime() - timestamp2.getTime()`, will result in correct number of milleseconds.

This test show indeed that the assert fails. You can fix it by adding additional zeros at the end.

```
@Test
public void validateDateComparison() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    try {
        Date dateStart = dateFormat.parse("2015-10-14 16:32:20.05");
        Date dateEnd = dateFormat.parse("2015-10-14 16:32:20.067");

        assertEquals(17, dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sample of [JodaTime duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_duration.html):

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2004, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// duration in ms between two instants
Duration dur = new Duration(start, end);

// calc will be the same as end
DateTime calc = start.plus(dur);
```

Not sure maybe [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) handles this [duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Durations) correct.

Comment: The OP was very clear that `dateOut.getTime() - dateIn.getTime()` is **not** giving the expected answer.

Comment: It not that obvious, to me, looking at the last code snippet, in the question

Comment: thats what I am doing, and its not working as expected